# Adjust WebStorm right click New menu

Tags: webstorm

I managed to remove the XSLT and CoffeScript entries. How do I remove the Scratch File one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`, select `Project View Popup Menu | New | ScratchFile`, press **Remove** button